# Paypal not working in sandbox account

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I created a PayPal account and also created a sandbox `personal account` as well as `business account`.

From `business account api` credentials I got `username:111abc.org` , `pwd :111`, `signature:A--hhshshhhhshsss`. Using these details  from test accounts I  Formatted my  API requests '

```
 define('API_USERNAME', '111abc.org');
 define('API_PASSWORD', '111');
 define('API_SIGNATURE', 'A--hhshshhhhshsss');
 define('API_ENDPOINT', 'https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp');
 define('PAYPAL_URL', 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webscr&cmd=_express-checkout&token=');
```

when I logged into the paypal account in my site  it shows  for adding the credit card no:, I copied it from  `business account api credentials` ,But it shows an error like this

`This credit card has been denied by the bank that issued your credit card.
 For details on why your card was denied, please contact your credit card issuer's customer service department. Or, you may want to try adding a different credit card.`

How can I test my paypal with sandbox account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using another test credit card number, you can generate these from the sandbox.  Otherwise, I provided some test Visa credit card numbers below.

4024007128707576
4539805151652124
4539139443918832
4716590741304528
4929181369786890
4539585085827139
4024007104385751
4485728803730862
4716879534966209
4556279316725340